# change body class according to storeview in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have two store views one is default and another is arabic. I need the store have to take another body class which is written for arabic. How to do change the class of the body while clicking arabic button

Answer (score 5):

Create one module name Vendor_Module:

Create an event on **layout_load_before** like below:
Path of **events.xml**:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

**events.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module_add_body_class" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddClassToBody" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create the observer class under:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AddClassToBody.php

Code for **AddClassToBody.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddClassToBody implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $pageConfig;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        PageConfig $pageConfig, 
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $store_code = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        $bodyClass = '';
        if($store_code == 'en'){
            $bodyClass = 'english';
        }elseif($store_code == 'nl'){
            $bodyClass = 'dutch';
        }else{
            $bodyClass = 'other';
        }
        $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass($bodyClass);   
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put your store codes in observer.

Comment: Is it working fine?

Comment: I am having one store and multiple storeviews..will it work?

Comment: Yes it should work

Comment: Use `$this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getCode();` if you want to get the website code instead of the store code